# Search string in file and return next line (in Java)

Tags: java, string, file, string-comparison

As my title says. I need to search through a file for a string. When its found, I need the next line.
It's a file like this:

> hello
>
> world

When "hello" is found, "world" needs to be returned.

```
File file = new File("testfile");
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
  scanner = new Scanner(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

if (scanner != null) {
  String line;
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line == "hello") {
      line = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```

It reads through the file but it doesn't find the word "hello".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (line == "hello") {
```

should be

```
if ("hello".equals(line)) {
```

You have to use equals() method to check if two string objects are equal. `==` operator in case of String(and all objects) only checks if two reference variables refer to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (line == "hello")
```

should be changed to

```
if (line.contains("hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `==` operator to compare two strings use
`if(line.compareTo("hello") == 0)`